# Отличающиеся данные в дашборде юзера

Tags: обсуждение

У меня пока какой-то странной и не понятной мне причине отличаются показатели общих проверок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или я не понимаю смысла в этих данных и они отвечают за разные показатели) не могу понять чем это вызвано и от чего зависит. Может у кого-то такое встречалось?

Comment: Я уже виже два одинаковых числа. Возможно просто кэш тормозит у SO.

Comment: @defaultlocale, хм... я тоже вижу уже два одинаковых числа)) тогда вопрос глупый)) хотя вначале выглядело странно )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Они могут не поспевать друг за другом как я понимаю из-за кеша. У меня тоже так было когда я зарабатывал этот знак.

Comment: Я понял)) просто думал может это у меня глюк где-то)